# Is the definition of recursive function unchanged if we restrict substitution to binary composition?

Tags: logic, computability, recursive-algorithms

When defining recursive functions, are the following two statements equivalent?$$f:\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^m, g:\mathbb{N}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^k \text{ recursive}\implies g\circ f \text{ recursive}$$
and
$$f_1:\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{N},...,f_m:\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{N} \text{ and }g:\mathbb{N}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \text{ recursive}\implies g(f_1,...,f_m) \text{ recursive.} $$

The first statement is a lemma in my notes, while the second is used in the definition. Nothing is said about the respective arities of the functions, for the first statement it only says 'composition of recursive functions is recursive', so I wrote that $g$ maps to $\mathbb{N}^k$. Is it possible to replace the second statement with the first in the definition and to obtain the second one as a consequence?

Another question: What is the name of the function $(f_1,...,f_m):\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, when $f_1,...,f_m$ are already given? I read a text where $g(f_1,...,f_n)$ was called 'composition' as well, but I only know composition as pointwise composition for two functions. Is there another name for said function, and the kind of composition resulting from it being composed with another function?

Comment: The second statement is usually taken as part of the [definition of recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Μ-recursive_function) What definition are you using?

Comment: @Rob Arthan I'm using this definition as well. So is the second statement stronger than the first one? I think I overheard my lecturer saying that those are equivalent, but it may be that I misheard him.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Hm I don't get this sorry. Are we talking about the same direction, i.e. from the first to the second statement? If I want to go from the second to the first one I just use $f_1:=f, m_1:=m$

Comment: @Rob Arthan Yes this is what I am asking. I'm sorry but I don't know how to call this $(f_1,...,f_n)$, which is why I used the original title. Also this composition: $g(f_1,...,f_n)$ is no ordinary composition, since it put the $f_1,...,f_n$ together somehow. What is the right way to call it?

Comment: @Rob Arthan $g\circ f$ is what I know as composition.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I'm pretty sure this is exactly what the title says. Feel free to edit it to your liking if you think it doesn't.

Comment: @Rob Arthan But this is what I am asking in the title: Whether defining $g\circ f$ as recursive is the same as defining $g(f_1,...,f_m)$ as recursive, given already recursive functions. So it's a kind of an induction step since I'm already assuming some recursive functions to be given. I explicitly wrote 'defining'.

Comment: You need to fix the question so that it is clear about what definitions you are using and what variants you are considering: the most common definition, e.g., as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) only has recursive function $\Bbb{N}^m\to\Bbb{N}$ not $\Bbb{N}^m\to\Bbb{N}^n$ for $n > 1$. So for users of that definition, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I fixed the question, but I still don't see how you would change the title. To me it says exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @See: I've tidied away some of my old comments. The confusion about the title is that your second statement is often referred to as the rule of composition. An alternative name is the "rule of substitution". So perhaps we could compromise on the title: "Is the definition of recursive functions unchanged if substitution is restricted to binary composition?", so I've made that change: please change again if you are not happy. However, we still need to know what definition of recursive function you are using that includes functions with values in $\Bbb{N}^n$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: See [Primitive recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) : **Composition**. First, note that functions are ... functions, i.e. $f : \mathbb N^m \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: Thus, with "usual" composition, we have $f : \mathbb N^m \to \mathbb N$ and then $g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, in order that $g \circ f$ makes sense.

Comment: The "generalized" composition of recursion theory has : $f_i : \mathbb N^m \to \mathbb N$, for $i=1, \ldots, n$, and thus $g : \mathbb N^n \to \mathbb N$, in order to allow for : $g(f_1(x_1, \ldots, x_m), \ldots , f_n (x_1, \ldots, x_m))$.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the definition of recursive function unchanged if we restrict substitution to binary composition?

I take "binary composition" to mean what is written on the second line of the question.

The answer is then Yes. This is because a sequence of functions $f_1, \ldots, f_m \colon \mathbb{N}^m \to \mathbb{N}$ are all computable if and only if the function
$
f\colon \mathbb{N}^m \to \mathbb{N}^m$ such that
$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_m) = (f_1(x_1,\ldots, x_m),\ldots,f_m(x_1, \ldots, x_m))$$
is computable, and in any case for this $f$ we have
$g \circ f = g(f_1, \ldots, f_m)$.

Clearly, if $f$ is computable, then so are each of its coordinate functions. Conversely, if $f_1,\ldots, f_m$ are all computable, I can combine their programs together to make a single function that returns an element of $\mathbb{N}^m$.

Really, the use of multiple inputs for a computable function is just a matter of convention. The entire notion of "computability" would be essentially unchanged if we only look at computable functions of *one* variable. The only difference that that, when we want to compute a function that "naively" takes two or more variables, we have to encode the input correctly. For example, instead of computing
$$
g(x,y) = x + y
$$
we could compute
$$
h(z) = \begin{cases}
x + y & \text{if } z = 2^x3^y \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
We would just have to send $h$ the number $2^x3^y$ whenever we wanted to compute $g(x,y)$. The same thing could be done for any computable function $g$ of any number of variables. As long as we are willing to prepare the input correctly, there is no need for the function to take more than one natural number input.  Once we make this switch, the entire notion of "generalized" composition disappears.

The reason that is not generally done is so that computability theory will resemble mathematical practice more closely, and to avoid having to talk about pairing operations on natural numbers so early in the theory. But there is nothing "more" about computability that comes from having multiple inputs, they just make the syntax look nicer in some ways.

This is very similar to the fact that we don't really gain any new amount of computability by adding additional input or output tapes to a Turing machine; anything that can be computed by a Turing machine with multiple input and output tapes can be computed by a Turing machine with one of each, as along as we prepare the input correctly and interpret the output correctly.

Comment: I understand the argument, but I am looking for a formal proof. Given that I defined the projection functions $p^n_k$, as well as $+,\cdot$ and $1_<$ as recursive, and then define for recursive $f:\mathbb{N}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^n,g:\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ this composition: $g\circ f$ as being recursive as well, how do I proof for recursive $f_1,...,f_k:\mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $g:\mathbb{N}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^m$ that $g(f_1,...,f_k)$ is recursive. Not by giving an procedure to compute the values, but using my definition of composition I defined beforehand.

Comment: I am not clear about what your formalism actually includes. The basic functions you mentioned all return single numbers. You would need to start by having a formal system in which you can actually define a computable function that returns values in $\mathbb{N}^m$ for some $m \geq 2$. For example, in your system, if $f_1, f_2 \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ are computable, how do you prove that $F(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x)$ is a computable function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^2$?  Once you indicate how that should work, I think it will be more clear how to answer your question here.

Comment: I suspect you will need to introduce a variety of  formal pairing functions into your system.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by what my formalism includes, sorry. I am taking an introductory course in mathematical logic, and we actually started recursive functions with the two definitions given in my last comment, and also defining the minimisation operator $\mu $as being recursive. You wrote 'if $f_1,f_2$ are computable, how do you prove that $F(x)$ is computable.' This is exactly the core of my opening question. Is it possible to prove this given only my definitions and e.g. some analysis, or would I have to extend my formal definition of 'recursive'.